# Unit testing custom AuthorizationFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, authorization

We did custom authorization attribute and want this to be covered by unit test. Unfortunately I don't have any idea how to unit test such kind of staff. Could you advise please?

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
   {
      var ts = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(TokenService));
        try
            {
                var token = GetHeader(actionContext.Request);
                if (token == null)
                {
                    actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                    {
                        Content = new StringContent("Token not found")
                    };
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    var tks = ts as TokenService;
                    var tkn = Task.Run(() => tks.FindToken(token)).Result;
                    if (tkn.ValidTill > DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        var us = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(UserService));
                        var uss = us as UserService;
                        var user = Task.Run(() => uss.FindByTokenValue(token)).Result;
                        if (user != null)
                        {
                            if (!_roles.Contains(user.RoleName))
                            {
                                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                                {
                                    Content = new StringContent("You role permission is not enough")
                                };
                                return;
                            }
                            var identity = new Identity { Name = user.Login, IsAuthenticated = true };
                            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new[] { user.RoleName });
                            actionContext.RequestContext.Principal = principal;
                            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
                            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
                            _roles = null;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                            {
                                Content = new StringContent("User not found")
                            };
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                        {
                            Content = new StringContent($"Token valid till {tkn.ValidTill}")
                        };
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent($"Authorization error: {ex.Message}")
                };
                return;
            }
        }
```

Test that should be passed:
- Token is exist.
- Token is valid for this DateTime.
- User role is valid.
P.S. Please don't ask me why we did this instead of using ASP.NET Identity, that's was not my solution, I prefer ASP.NET Identity.

Comment: Which version/edition of visual studio are you using?

Comment: @mark_h, 2015/Community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is nothing really special about this. So for example using Moq:

```
[Test]
public void OnAuthorization_ReturnsErrorWhenThereIsNoToken()
{
  var resolver = new Mock<IDependencyResolver>();
  resolver.Setup(x => x.GetService(It.IsAny<Type>())).Returns(
    (Type t) =>
      {
        if (t == typeof(TokenService))
        {
          return new TokenService();
        }

        if (t == typeof(TokenService))
        {
          return new UserService();
        }

        return null;
      });

  var original = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver;

  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver.Object;
  var ctx = new HttpActionContext
              {
                ControllerContext =
                  new HttpControllerContext { Request = new HttpRequestMessage() }
              };

  var target = new Attrr();

  target.OnAuthorization(ctx); // no token

  Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, ctx.Response.StatusCode);
  Assert.AreEqual("Token not found", (ctx.Response.Content as StringContent).ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

  // we need this to ensure the test state is restored after test
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = original;
}
```

Obviously then you need to keep replicating behaviours (i'm hoping your TokenService and UserService are actually `interface`'d.